# Write Errors to LOG file - PHP mySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using `mysqli` to handle Database operations and want to Log each and every error to a file `sql-error.log`

Code i am using is below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->_con,"CALL PROCEDURE_NAME(2)");
if(false===$result){
  $error = 'Error calling stored procedure insert_product. Error No: ' . 
            mysqli_errno($this->_con) . ': ' . mysqli_error($this->_con);
  error_log($error . "Date::" . date("l jS \of F, Y, h:i:s A") ."\n", 3, "/sql-errors.log");
  exit();
}
```

And on cPanel, my `Functions.php` folder structure is as below:

```
/public_html/site_name/sql/functions/
```

But when i execute the query then i got a below Error

> [15-Jan-2016 04:21:06 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  error_log(/sql-errors.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /public_html/site_name/sql/functions/Functions.php on line ***

How to give permissions to write to this file and will `error_log` automatically creates file?

Comment: Add permission to a folder where `error_log` is located

Comment: like, i shall change from `755` to `777` . Is it safe to do so??

Comment: Yes it will be safe, you need to change 755 to 777

Comment: 600 is safe : `The owner may read and write a file. All others have no rights. A common setting for data files that the owner wants to keep private.`

Comment: changing Permission to `0777` has not worked and is still a problem

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 600 foldername/ -R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think PHP is trying to write on the `root` folder which it doesn't have permission to access to. So, I'd rather use the `__DIR__` constant to access the desired folder where the log files reside.

Let's say you have a log folder `/public_html/site_name/log/`. Since your script is in `/public_html/site_name/sql/functions/` what I'd program is:

```
error_log( $error . "Date::" . date( "l jS \of F, Y, h:i:s A" ) . "\n", 3, _DIR_ . "/../../log/sql-errors.log" );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Brilliant @timo ... Worked like Charm :) and that too without changing Permisions.